# Unable to display image coming from ajax response in img src

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, image

i am using  a function which will crop the image on the fly and return the resized image. Issue is that if i am using it in jQuery, I am exposing my API KEY, which is sensitive. So i am using ajax function to display the image.

Here is My JQuery Code

```
var bgImg = "Actual_image_path.jpeg";
var bgImgSrc    = "whatFor=imageResize&width=640&height=480&path="+bgImg;
$.ajax({
    url:"/ajaxcalls.php",
    type: 'POST',
    data:bgImgSrc,
    cache:false,
    async:false,
    success:function(data){
        bgImgHtml = '<img id="img_bgImg" src="data:image/jpeg;base64,' + data + '" class="" />';
    },
    error:function(){
        $(".cityblurb").text("");
    }
});
```

Here is my ajaxcalls.php

```
foreach($_POST as $key=>$value){
    $apiUrl.="&$key=".$value;
}

$apiURL     = APIURL."token=".KEY.$apiUrl;
$result     = curl_get_file_contents($apiURL);
echo $result;

function curl_get_file_contents($URL) { 
    header("Content-Type: image/jpeg");
    $c = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_URL, $URL);
    $contents = curl_exec($c);
    $err  = curl_getinfo($c,CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    curl_close($c);
    if ($contents) return $contents;
    else return FALSE;
}
```

When I console, I can see the resized Image but unable to print it into html. All it is printing is those special characters of image.

Comment: `header("Content-Type: image/jpeg");` implies that you're going to return binary image data. But your `src="data:image/jpeg;base64` implies that the browser is expecting a base64-encoded string. Make your mind up which of those you actually want to do.

Comment: BTW I don't see why you need AJAX for this. Just set the `src` of the `img` tag to the `/ajaxcalls.php?whatfor=...etc` URL directly. (It would be a GET, but you can easily change the PHP to cope with reading GET parameters instead of POST).